# DataType interval is not supported - Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running a query on AWS EMR and the query errors out on this line -

```
to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + CAST(concat(mycolumn, ' seconds') AS INTERVAL)  AS date_col
```

The error - `DataType interval is not supported.(line 521, pos 82)`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try `expr(concat('INTERVAL ', mycolumn, ' seconds'))`

Comment: @nabongs It says - Undefined function: 'expr'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.

Comment: Did you import `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: What is the output you're expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

I think Spark supports the interval key word.  It would be used as:

```
to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + mycolumn * interval '1 second' AS date_col
```

Comment: It says - cannot resolve '(CAST(my_column` AS INT) * interval 1 seconds)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(CAST(my_column AS INT) * interval 1 seconds)' (int and calendarinterval). How do I convert my column to interval?

Comment: Same issue for me: cannot resolve '...' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '...' (calendarinterval and bigint).

Comment: @C.Yduqoli . . . You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: I got this to work with a newer version of Spark. Version 2.4.4 caused above error, Version 3.0.1 is working. Maybe this answer should edited to note that older versions of Spark might not work.